Upgrade VSCode version on SSH (while on remote extension)
So, I use a Mac M1. I have a UTM Ubuntu VM set up that I do some of my development on. I have the Github Copilot extension locally on my M1, but when I am sshed onto the Ubuntu VM (through the VSCode remote ssh extension), I am unable to install the Copilot extension.
This is the error message pop up I get:

Can't install 'github.copilot-chat' extension because it is not compatible with the current version of Visual Studio Code (version 1.75.0).

Running code -v on the terminal there gives version 1.75.0.
So, I manually went onto my VM, and upgraded VSCode there. On the actual machine, when I have logged on, running code -v gives version 1.88.0
Then, when I switch back to the remote extension, having quit and restarted, I still get the old version: 1.75.0.
I tried upgrading VSCode via the command line on the remote ssh extension too, but the version remains the same.
My understanding is that the 1.75.0 version is the reason behind me not being able to install the Github Copilot extension on ssh to the Ubuntu VM on vscode.
How can I fix the version to solve this problem?
